# number of moves in the "memory"-game

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

Suppose, a player with a perfect memory starts with $2n$ cards in the game
memory.

A move consists of choosing two cards, the game ends if all pairs are found.

Let $X$ be the number of moves the player needs.

- What is $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$ depending on $n$ ?
- Can $P(X=k)$ be calculated for all natural $k\ge n$ ?
- What is the maximum possible value for $X$ ? (It cannot exceed $2n$, assuming the player makes no mistake (perfect memory)) ?

For $n=1$, we have $X=1$ with probability $1$.

For $n=2$, we have $X=2$ with probability $\frac{1}{3}$ and $X=3$ with probability $\frac{2}{3}$

The probability $P(X=n)$ is given by $\frac{1}{3\times ...\times (2n-1)}$
for $n\ge 2$

Comment: I started to write up an answer, but it is getting extremely lengthy. Instead I will leave some notes: a player with perfect memory will turn over each card in order, and may leave them upturned. With probability $1/(2n-1)$ on any given turn, he will get lucky and be able to remove the two cards he upturned; he may wait until the end to mop up. He will only deviate from this order if he knows where the mate of the first card he turns up is, so that will be the second card chosen, instead of overturning a new card.

Comment: This last fact unfortunately complicates the analysis, and makes what I was intending to write as a solution basically invalid. I was intending to work under the assumption that $2k-2$ cards were known on turn $k$, but because the player will instead only turn over one new card on some turns, this is not true.